# debugging error at the end of the console

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm a student and I studying c++.

This is my cpp code

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CFood output;   
    output.whatFunc();
    cout<<"my outputs"<<endl<<output<<endl;
    return 0;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const CFood& output)
{
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
   {
   outputStream <<"1 : "<<output.m_strName[i]<<" 2 : "<<output.m_servingSize[i]<<"g "<<"3 : "<<
      output.m_calorie[i]<<"cal "<<"4 : "<<output.m_transFat[i]<<"g"<<endl;

   }

    return outputStream;
}
```

When I debug it, It work. But the end of the console, it gives me error message;;;

It says "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in work.exe [5796]"

My header filed is

```
class CFood
{
public:
    CFood(void);
    ~CFood(void);

private:
    string m_strName[7];
    double m_servingSize[7];
    double m_calorie[7];
   double m_transFat[7];

public:
    void whatFunc(void); 
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream,const CFood& output);
}
```

I think there is something wrong in my code..And I think it's CFood output;(Just thinking..)

Do you know why it has debug error?

++Sorry, I forgot the whatFunc(void)

This is code

```
void CFood::whatFunc(void) //
{
   m_strName[0]="chicken";
   m_strName[1]="rice";
   m_strName[2]="meat";
   m_strName[3]="strawberry";
   m_strName[4]="apple";
   m_strName[5]="water";
   m_strName[6]="juice";
   m_servingSize[0]=10;
   m_servingSize[1]=20;
   m_servingSize[2]=30;
   m_servingSize[3]=40;
   m_servingSize[4]=50;
   m_servingSize[5]=60;
   m_servingSize[6]=70;
   m_calorie[0]=10.45;
   m_calorie[1]=20.57;
   m_calorie[2]=30.78;
   m_calorie[3]=40.23;
   m_calorie[4]=50.85;
   m_calorie[5]=60.73;
   m_calorie[6]=70.27;
   m_transFat[0]=0.01;
   m_transFat[1]=0.02;
   m_transFat[2]=0.03;
   m_transFat[3]=0.04;
   m_transFat[4]=0.05;
   m_transFat[5]=0.06;
   m_transFat[6]=0.07;



}
```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When you stepped through the code with the debugger, what line was giving you issues?

Comment: Your header file is missing the `class` keyword, opening and closing brace.

Comment: At the end of my code.-After the return 0;

Comment: where should I write class keyword....?

Comment: Please provide void whatFunc(void) source code.

Comment: Most likely something in your destructor ~CFood(void) is causing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well its difficult to tell what exactly goes wrong without full source code. In my humble opinion, entire source lefts much to be desired. Placing obviously linked data in the bunch of the unlinked arrays with static size is not a very good pattern. Instead try something like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>

struct CFoodItem{
    std::string m_strName;
    double m_servingSize;
    double m_calorie;
    double m_transFat;
};

class CFood
{
public:
    void AddFoodItem(const CFoodItem& cItem);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outputStream, const CFood& output);
private:
    std::vector<CFoodItem> m_vItems;
};


std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outputStream, const CFood& output)
{
    for (auto i = output.m_vItems.begin(); i != output.m_vItems.end(); ++i)
    {
        outputStream << "1 : " << i->m_strName << " 2 : " << i->m_servingSize << "g " << "3 : " <<
            i->m_calorie << "cal " << "4 : " << i->m_transFat << "g" << std::endl;

    }

    return (outputStream);
}

void CFood::AddFoodItem(const CFoodItem& cItem)
{
    m_vItems.push_back(cItem);
}

int __cdecl main(void)
{
    CFood output;
    CFoodItem itm;
    itm.m_strName = "some food";
    itm.m_servingSize = 100500;
    itm.m_calorie = 42;
    itm.m_transFat = 42;
    output.AddFoodItem(itm);
    std::cout << "my outputs" << std::endl << output << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```